# Didn't find class "com.example.app.MainActivity"

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

I got this error in flutter debugging the android build.
I didn't find out the exact solution for this.
Please help to solve this.

Launching lib/main.dart on SM M105F in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
Purging debug resources in release build
✓  Built build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app-debug.apk.
Installing build/app/outputs/flutter-apk/app.apk...
E/AndroidRuntime(22297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
E/AndroidRuntime(22297): Process: com.example.app, PID: 22297
E/AndroidRuntime(22297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.app/com.example.app.MainActivity}: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.app-8SDv03NkHqZSCPu3ZprpAQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.app-8SDv03NkHqZSCPu3ZprpAQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.app-8SDv03NkHqZSCPu3ZprpAQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3449)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3703)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2216)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:237)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7948)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1075)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.app.MainActivity" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.app-8SDv03NkHqZSCPu3ZprpAQ==/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.app-8SDv03NkHqZSCPu3ZprpAQ==/lib/arm, /data/app/com.example.app-8SDv03NkHqZSCPu3ZprpAQ==/base.apk!/lib/armeabi-v7a, /system/lib, /vendor/lib]]
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:196)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:379)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.AppComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(AppComponentFactory.java:95)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at androidx.core.app.CoreComponentFactory.instantiateActivity(CoreComponentFactory.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1251)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3437)
E/AndroidRuntime(22297):    ... 11 more

Answer (score 0):

Open your AndroidManifest.xml and check if you have com.example.app.MainActivity :

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.app.MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```

Comment: I have tried that but that's not working for me. The same issue still coming.

Comment: @AbhishekPandey. how did you solve this?

Comment: @Paul what is your package name in main activity?

Comment: @AliPunjabi I had a different problem. After renaming my project I had not changed the package name, where .MainActivity is requested. I simply searched through all instances with the previous app name and resolved old names.

Answer (score 0):

In case useful to someone, in addition to previous answers: I've that error after migrating from java to kotlin with migration procedure in android studio.

I find out that Android studio (Electric Eel 2022.1.1 Patch 1) didn't add in build.gradle for app module this:

`apply plugin: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android`'

after adding it, clean and build, everything works again.